# css - grid div 2x2 centered but turns to 1x4 on smaller screens

Tags: html, css

hello this is driving me mad can anyone help. i want a grid of divs 2x2 centered on a large screen but when viewed on smaller screen moves to 1x4 but still centered. so far i have this it works but aligns left on small 1x4 view. i have tried to us inline-block instead of float:left  but then you cant add any further content with the #frame-block. the width must be fixed widths at 500px

```
#frame-block {
width: 500px;
border: 2px #0066FF solid;
margin:5px;
height:400px;
float:left;
}


#frame-container {
  text-align: center;
}

#frame-main {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}​

<div id="frame-container">

  <div id="frame-main">

     <div id="frame-block"></div>
      <div id="frame-block"></div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: sorry?..what means " you cant add any further content with the #frame-block. " can you explain what do you want exactly?.

Comment: You can't use the same ID on more than one element in the same page. More: http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/when-using-ids-can-be-a-pain-in-the-class/.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [media queries](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/08/10/techniques-for-gracefully-degrading-media-queries/#more-104692) to make the `#frame-block` twice as wide on a certain resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: http://dabblet.com/gist/3734237.

*One* of your problems was reusing IDs. IDs are unique and should only be used once per page. Here's even more reading on it: http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/.

In my amendment to your code, I changed the IDs to classes, gave .frame-block 'display: inline-block' instead of 'float: left'.

I'd suggest using relative units as opposed to pixel units so that you need only change the base font-size on your 'body' to adapt on smaller screens that are below 500px. You can read more about it here: http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/